# How to change element in another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which has several `<tr>` elements, which contains three things:

- `<td>` with number and dot behind it (like this: `<td>19.</td>`)
- `<td>` with description
- `<td>` with checkbox

```html
<table>
  <!-- Some other <tr>s there... -->
  <tr id="somethingGeneratedWhichIDontKnow">
    <td id="aduju1j">13.</td>
    <td id="ajdi1">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
    <td id="3j21">
      <input type="checkbox" id="3125ac_a">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Some other <tr>s there... -->
</table>
```

I need to find `<tr>` element which has 1st `<td>` with some number and change the checkbox there.

So my question is: How can I find the right checkbox? ID of elements is generated by web, so I can't select it by ID. I accept both javascript and jQuery answers.

I'm new to JS and jQuery so thanks you for all your help :-)

Comment: You can use `:contains` or `filter()` to find a cell by an arbitrary property. See the documentation for more details: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: try $( "tr:first" )

Comment: Can you explain what you want to change in the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var checkbox = $('td:contains("13.")').eq(0).parent().find(":checkbox")
```

Comment: Use `$('td:contains("13.")').eq(0).parent().find(":checkbox")`. Getting a jQuery object then turning it in to a DOMElement, then back in to a jQuery object is painfully redundant.

Comment: OP wants to check first td of tr. It might be changed to `$('tr > td:contains("13.")')`.

Answer (score 0):

Find a `tr` where the first `td` contains a number, then use that `tr` as the basis to find the `checkbox`.:

```js
// find the tr
var $tr = $('table tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('td:first').text().match("[0-9]+");
}).first();

// find the checkbox inside a td of the found tr
var $cb = $tr.find("td :checkbox");
console.log($cb.attr('id'));

//here $cb is the checkbox
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <!-- Some other <tr>s there... -->
  <tr id="somethingGeneratedWhichIDontKnow">
    <td id="aduju1j">13.</td>
    <td id="ajdi1">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
    <td id="3j21">
      <input type="checkbox" id="3125ac_a">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Some other <tr>s there... -->
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
var chkList = $('#tbl tr').map(function(t){
    return {
        num: $(this).children('td:first').text(),
        chk: $(this).find(':checkbox')
    }
}).get();

console.log('checkboxesList', chkList);
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zpavrgeo/